# How to load image files dataset to TensorFlow Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, dataset, tensor

I'm trying to create a model to classify some plants, just so I can learn how to use TensorFlow. The problem is that every [good example](https://github.com/ianlewis/tensorflow-examples/blob/master/notebooks/TensorFlow%20MNIST%20tutorial.ipynb) that I can use as reference is loading a `.csv` dataset and I want to load a `.jpeg` dataset (could be `.png` or `.jpg` as well).

Those examples even use a built in dataset like:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

My dataset is organized in folders containing the label of the flower and inside there are the images organized by numbers.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me assume that your folder structure is as follows：

```
├── testfiles
|   ├── BougainvilleaGlabra
|   |   ├── BougainvilleaGlabra_001.jpeg
|   |   ├── *.jpeg
|   ├── HandroanthusChrysotrichus
|   |   ├── HandroanthusChrysotrichus_001.jpeg
|   |   ├── *.jpeg
|   ├── SpathodeaVenusta
|   |   ├── SpathodeaVenusta_001.jpeg
|   |   ├── *.jpeg
|   ├──TibouchinaMutabilis
|   |   ├── TibouchinaMutabilis_001.jpeg
|   |   ├── *.jpeg
├── test.py
```

First you need to get all the image paths.

```
import glob,os

path = 'testfiles/'
files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "*/*.jpeg", recursive=True)]
print(files)

['testfiles/HandroanthusChrysotrichus/HandroanthusChrysotrichus_002.jpeg', 'testfiles/HandroanthusChrysotrichus/HandroanthusChrysotrichus_001.jpeg', ...]
```

Then you need encode every class to number.

```
label_map = {'BougainvilleaGlabra':0,
             'HandroanthusChrysotrichus':1,
             'SpathodeaVenusta':2,
             'TibouchinaMutabilis':3,}
label = [label_map[os.path.basename(file).split('_')[0]] for file in files]
print(label)

[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

And then you can use `tf.data.Dataset`. You need a function to read image and resieze them to the same shape.

```
import tensorflow as tf
def read_image(filename,label):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [28, 28])
    return image_resized,label

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((files,label))
# you can use batch() to set batch_size
dataset = dataset.map(read_image).shuffle(1000).batch(2)
print(dataset.output_shapes)
print(dataset.output_types)

(TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(28), Dimension(28), Dimension(None)]), TensorShape([Dimension(None)]))
(tf.float32, tf.int32)
```

Finally you define iterator to get batch data.

```
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(2):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        batch_image,batch_label = sess.run(next_element)
        print(batch_image.shape)
        print(batch_label.shape)

(2, 28, 28, 4)
(2,)
(2, 28, 28, 4)
(2,)
```

Comment: Thanks for the aswer, it helped me a lot. Do you have a link to an example using this type of dataset being used to train a model?

Comment: @PedroVieira You can train the model in the same way as the links in your question, as well as [How to use Dataset in TensorFlow](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dataset-in-tensorflow-c758ef9e4428) and [TensorFlow Dataset API tutorial – build high performance data pipelines](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/tensorflow-dataset-tutorial/). Or you can use `tf.estimator` like [Datasets for Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets_for_estimators).